Как убрать полосы между заголовками на GitHub: HTML
Как на GitHub убрать эти полосы между двумя заголовками? Заголовок находятся по центру, а "I just started", должно быть под ним, как уточнение. Уже многое перепробовал, но никак не получается(((

<div align="center">  
  <h2>⚙️Tools and skills</h2><p><small>I just started</small></p>
</div>

Код, который используется на данный момент на данный момент

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

"На GitHub" - это где? Через Github pages публикуете или просто в markdown файл вставляете?

в read.me файле, прям в гит хабе пишу

Github свои css стили применяет. Теоретически - переопределить стили, чтобы этой линии не было.
